# Can anyone identify this second hand bike?

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, triathlon

I am looking into getting a new (for me) road / TT bike and this came up but I think it isn't a Specialized Shiv...

[image: Specialized Shiv TT AL]

many thanks

Comment: It appears to be a 2012 model: https://www.evanscycles.com/specialized-shiv-elite-a1-2012-triathlon-bike-EV172764

Comment: Wow, thank you for the very very quick response. i dont suppose you have an opinion on the bike for a new rider?

Comment: New rider?  Borrow a bike from a friend, or dig one out of your parents' shed.

Comment: well not 'new', been trying to ride more over the last year, now i'm doing between 50 & 150km per week depending on spare time, on an old mtb but i've never had a road bike before. i've just about run out of gears on the flat so i guess its time for some kind of upgrade...

Comment: Spin faster. And get a road bike, not a time trial bike unless you compete in time trials or triathlon.

Comment: Yeah, this is a very special-purpose bike. Get a more general-purpose road bike first, I'd say, unless this is a stupidly good deal.

Comment: Maintaining the riding position that this bike has is only worth it if you are doing a time trial. The huge profile rims are very affected by side winds and can get you in trouble. It's more oriented to flat, well paved roads, riding up it is also a disadvantage , I believe you can only shift gears from over there in the long bars which is also worse than in a typical road bike

Comment: If it’s a stupidly good deal, it may be stolen.  Always be sure to check the serial numbers against the many web based serial number checkers like BikeIndex.com etc.